# Text is not selectable and it's causing SEO problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo, splidejs

We have two sites that has same problem.
We are using sliders by [SplideJS](https://splidejs.com/).
Wince we have 2 branches, we need to have 2 types of data in our homepage in any given time. And once a branch is selected e.g. The Netherlands, the whole page should display the content about The Netherlands. we previously used sliders and tabs but they had a synchronization problem so we switched to whole sliders.

I need to make the price in [this section](https://unusualoffice.com/#pricing) show in google. Below, you can see the settings for SplideJS.

To summarize: I have **draggable slider** and **non-selectable text(s)**. I need to make these **texts show up in Google/SEO**.
!IMPORTANT NOTE: Our SEO expert said the text is seen as an image.

```js
    pricingSplide = new Splide('#pricingsplide', {
      speed: 400,
      type: 'loop',
      padding: '0rem',
      rewind: false,
      drag:true
    });
```

Comment: Your text isn't an image...the whole li is a draggable element

Comment: yes I figured. SplideJS has an option called "nodrag" but it won't enable the selectable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SplideJS applies [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) properties to the entire track.

You could potentially circumvent this by adding the following to your CSS:

```
.splide__track.splide__track--draggable {
  user-select: unset;
}
```

However, this may also affect the functionality of the slider so use with caution and also target specific sliders if possible.

Comment: Thank you we figured out this was the issue. Though rather than enabling user select for all, I enabled it just for the price element(s). You can check unusualoffice.com. Thank you.